# Delete fields data from NextJS Form with Server Actions

Tags: typescript, forms, next.js

I'm trying to ultilize Server Actions in NextJs 13.4, but I can't seem to delete the data in form fields once I submit the form.

**Form**

```
export default function PostForm() {
    return (
        <form action={addPost} className="rounded-md flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2">
            <LabeledInput name="title" label="Title"/>
            <LabeledInput name="subtitle" label="Subtitle"/>
            <LabeledTextArea name="content" label="Content"/>
            <Button>Add Post</Button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

**Inputs**

```
export const LabeledTextArea = ({ name, label }: LabeledTextareaProps) => (
    <div className={"flex flex-col items-start w-full"}>
        <label className="text-lg">{label}</label>
        <div className="mt-2 w-full">
          <textarea
              name={name}
              className="px-3 py-2 w-full rounded-md text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-none border border-gray-500"
              placeholder={`Your post ${name}`}
              required
          />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

```
export const LabeledInput = ({name, label, type = "text"}: LabeledInputProps) => (
    <div className={"flex flex-col items-start w-full"}>
        <label className="text-lg">{label}</label>
        <div className="mt-2 w-full">
            <input
                type={type}
                name={name}
                className="px-3 py-2 w-full rounded-md text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-none border border-gray-500"
                placeholder={`Your post ${name}`}
                required
            />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

**Server Action**

```
'use server'

import {revalidateTag} from "next/cache";
import axios from "axios";

export const addPost = async (form: FormData) => {
    const newPost: Post = {
        title: form.get('title')!.toString(),
        subtitle: form.get('subtitle')!.toString(),
        content: form.get('content')!.toString(),
        user: "Federiko98",
        date: new Date().toISOString()
    }

    await axios.post("https://myapi/posts", newPost).then(
        () => {
            revalidateTag('posts');

            // TODO - Clear form fields after submit (not working)
            form.delete('title');
            form.delete('subtitle');
            form.delete('content');
        }
    ).catch(
        (err) => console.log(err)
    )
}
```

There is also another error that my IDE (WebStorm) marks for me. The error message is in the form on the action attribute and reports:

```
TS2322: Type  (form: FormData) => Promise<void>  is not assignable to type  string 
index.d.ts(2121, 9): The expected type comes from property  action  which is declared here on type
DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>
```

However, this error does not affect the operation of the form.

I tried searching the NextJS official documentation and could not find a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77022220/how-to-erase-form-in-next-js-13-4-component-after-server-action/77023047#77023047