# How to erase form in next.js 13.4 component after server action?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, next.js, next.js13

I'm using next.js 13.4, typescript and resend for this component.

Actually, my code works well without erasing data from inputs, by using "action", which is commented. I started adding useState, but I encountered issues with formData and onSubmit. Can you please advise on how to best implement the ability to clear the form after submission?

```
'use client';

import { useSectionInView } from '@/utils/hooks';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SectionHeading from '../SectionHeading';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { fadeIn } from '@/utils/motion';
import SubmitBtn from './SubmitBtn';
import { sendEmail } from '@/utils/sendEmail';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

interface FormData {
    senderEmail: string;
    message: string;
}

export default function Contact() {
    const { ref } = useSectionInView('Contact');

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormData>({
        senderEmail: '',
        message: '',
    });

    const handleFormSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent, formData) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { data, error } = await sendEmail(formData);

        if (error) {
            toast.error(error);
        } else {
            toast.success('Email sent successfully!');
            setFormData({
                senderEmail: '',
                message: '',
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <motion.section
            className='section_margin w-[min(100%,38rem)] text-center'
            variants={fadeIn('down', 'tween', 0.5, 1.2)}
            initial='hidden'
            whileInView='show'
            ref={ref}
            id='contact'>
            <SectionHeading>Contact me</SectionHeading>
            <p className='text-gray-700 -mt-6 dark:text-white/80'>
                Please contact me directly at{'  '}
                <a className='underline' href='mailto:my@mail.com'>
                    my email
                </a>{' '}
                or through this form.
            </p>

            <form
                className='mt-10 flex flex-col dark:text-black'
                // action={async (formData) => {
                //     const { data, error } = await sendEmail(formData);

                //     if (error) {
                //         toast.error(error);
                //         return;
                //     }
                //     toast.success('Email sent successfully!');
                // }}
                onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                <input
                    type='email'
                    name='senderEmail'
                    className='h-14 px-4 rounded-lg borderBlack dark:bg-white dark:bg-opacity-80 dark:focus:bg-opacity-100 transition-all dark:outline-none'
                    required
                    maxLength={500}
                    placeholder='Your email'
                    value={formData.senderEmail}
                    onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, senderEmail: e.target.value })}
                />
                <textarea
                    name='message'
                    placeholder='Your message'
                    required
                    maxLength={5000}
                    className='h-52 my-3 rounded-lg borderBlack p-4 dark:bg-white dark:bg-opacity-80 dark:focus:bg-opacity-100 transition-all dark:outline-none'
                    value={formData.message}
                    onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, message: e.target.value })}
                />
                <SubmitBtn />
            </form>
        </motion.section>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you separete the form logic into a client component.

```
"use client"

const Form = () => {
  const ref=useRef(null)
  return (
    <form
      ref={ref}
      className="mt-10 flex flex-col dark:text-black"
      // formData is passed automatically here
      action={async formData=>{
          ref.current.reset()
          // current formData is not effected by .reset()
          await yourACtion(formData)
       }}
      // onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
    >
      <input
        type="email"
        name="senderEmail"
        className="h-14 px-4 rounded-lg borderBlack dark:bg-white dark:bg-opacity-80 dark:focus:bg-opacity-100 transition-all dark:outline-none"
        required
        maxLength={500}
        placeholder="Your email"
        value={formData.senderEmail}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, senderEmail: e.target.value })
        }
      />
      <textarea
        name="message"
        placeholder="Your message"
        required
        maxLength={5000}
        className="h-52 my-3 rounded-lg borderBlack p-4 dark:bg-white dark:bg-opacity-80 dark:focus:bg-opacity-100 transition-all dark:outline-none"
        value={formData.message}
        onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, message: e.target.value })}
      />
      <SubmitBtn />
    </form>
  );
};
```

when working with actions you should have a separate actions folder. if you are using action on client side, you cannot use `use server` inside the action but on top of the actions file

```
// actions.js
"use server"
export const yourAction=async ()=> {}
```

with this you can invoke the server action inside a client component. Now you can convert the client `Form` component into a controlled component with `useState` or `useRef`. to avoid unnecessary rendering, you may choose `useRef`